# Scanning all files in a directory ending with .wor

Tags: c, file, directory, counter

I am trying to write a c code to scan an entire directory for files ending with .wor, open each file and extract certain info from them.
So far my code successfully opens ALL files with in that directory, and scans them for the target words.  Is there a way for me to modify the code so it would scan only files ending with .wor?  I have tried the wildcard "*.wor" but it just gives me an error saying the symbol * and .wor is not recognized.
Thank you very much for the help!
(Btw I could not get the counter i added at the end to work either, im trying to use the integer "c" to increment each time a file is read, and display a total number of files read at the end.  It just gives me 0 right now.)

Here is my code:

```
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <string.h>
    #include <stdlib.h>
    #include <sys/types.h>
    #include <dirent.h>
    #include <unistd.h>
    #include <errno.h>

    int main(int argc, char **argv) {

char file[100];
char buff[100];
char delims[] = " :=";
char *result = NULL;
char *customer;
char *device;
char *testprog;
char *software;
char *dutboardid;
char *corlbox;
int i=0;
DIR * FD;
struct dirent* in_file;
int c = 0;


    FILE * ft = fopen ( "WorkOrderInfo.csv", "w" ) ;    /* Open file to write to*/
    if ( ft == NULL )
    {
           puts ( "Cannot open target file" ) ;
           exit( 1 ) ;
    }

    fprintf (ft, "Work Order,Customer,Device,Test_Prog,Software,DUT_board_id,Corl box\n");



/* Open Directory*/

if (NULL == (FD = opendir ("/home/iselabs/dwang/pinscale/workorder/practice"))) 
    {
    fprintf(stderr, "Error : Failed to open input directory - %s\n");
    fclose(ft);

    return 1;
    }


    while ((in_file = readdir(FD))) 
    {

    if (!strcmp (in_file->d_name, "."))
        continue;
    if (!strcmp (in_file->d_name, ".."))    
        continue;


    /* Open files to read from  */


    FILE * fs = fopen(in_file->d_name, "r");
    if (fs == NULL)
    {
        puts ("Cannot open source file");

        return 1;
    }

    /* Scanning each file for targeted words: */


while( fgets(buff, 100,fs) != NULL )      
{   
 result = strtok( buff, delims );          
    while(result != NULL){                   
            if((strcmp(result,"Customer")==0)){ 
        result = strtok(NULL,delims);  
        customer = (char*)malloc((strlen(result)+1)*sizeof(char));
        strcpy(customer, result);
        for(i=0;i<strlen(customer)+1;i++){ if(customer[i] == '\n') break; }
        customer[i] = ' ';
        }


            if((strcmp(result,"name")==0)){ 
        result = strtok(NULL,delims);  
        customer = (char*)malloc((strlen(result)+1)*sizeof(char));
        strcpy(customer, result);
        for(i=0;i<strlen(customer)+1;i++){ if(customer[i] == '\n') break; }
        customer[i] = ' ';
        }

            if(strcmp(result,"device")==0){ 
        result = strtok(NULL,delims);  
        device = (char*)malloc((strlen(result)+1)*sizeof(char));
        strcpy(device, result);
        for(i=0;i<strlen(device)+1;i++){ if(device[i] == '\n') break; } 
        device[i] = ' ';
        }


            if(strcmp(result,"test_prog")==0){ 
        result = strtok(NULL,delims);  
        testprog = (char*)malloc((strlen(result)+1)*sizeof(char));
        strcpy(testprog, result);
        for(i=0;i<strlen(testprog)+1;i++){ if(testprog[i] == '\n') break; } 
        testprog[i] = ' ';
        }

            if(strcmp(result,"Rev")==0 || strcmp(result,"use")==0){ 
        result = strtok(NULL,delims);  
        software = (char*)malloc((strlen(result)+1)*sizeof(char));
        strcpy(software, result);
        for(i=0;i<strlen(software)+1;i++){ if(software[i] == '\n') break; } 
        software[i] = ' ';
        }

        if(strcmp(result,"rev")==0){ 
        result = strtok(NULL,delims);  
        software = (char*)malloc((strlen(result)+1)*sizeof(char));
        strcpy(software, result);
        for(i=0;i<strlen(software)+1;i++){ if(software[i] == '\n') break; } 
        software[i] = ' ';
        }

            if(strcmp(result,"DUT_board_id")==0){ 
        result = strtok(NULL,delims);  
        dutboardid = (char*)malloc((strlen(result)+1)*sizeof(char));
        strcpy(dutboardid, result);
        for(i=0;i<strlen(dutboardid)+1;i++){ if(dutboardid[i] == '\n') break; } 
        dutboardid[i] = ' ';
        }                   
        else if (strcmp(result,"DUT_board_id")==1){
        corlbox = "N/A";
        }

            if(strcmp(result,"box")==0){ 
        result = strtok(NULL,delims);  
        corlbox = (char*)malloc((strlen(result)+1)*sizeof(char));
        strcpy(corlbox, result);
        for(i=0;i<strlen(corlbox)+1;i++){ if(corlbox[i] == '\n') break; } 
        corlbox[i] = ' ';
        }
        else if (strcmp(result,"box")==1){
        corlbox = "N/A";
        }           
        result = strtok(NULL,delims);
    }

}


fprintf (ft, "%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s\n", file, customer, device, testprog, software, dutboardid, corlbox);


fclose (fs) ;
printf("hey\n");
c = c++;                             /*Increments c by 1 every time a file is read */
}

printf("total files scanned: %d \n", c);
    fclose ( ft ) ;
return 0;
```

}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can manually check if each filename ends in `.wor` like this:

```
size_t len = strlen(in_file->d_name);
if (len >= 4 && memcmp(in_file->d_name + len - 4, ".wor", 4) == 0)
{
    // The filename ends in ".wor" (case-sensitive).  Note that this also
    // accepts the file whose entire name is ".wor".
}
```

Alternatively, you can instead use the [`glob(3)`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/glob) function to get the list of filenames matching a particular wildcard:

```
// Error checking omitted for expository purposes
glob_t globbuf;
glob("/home/iselabs/dwang/pinscale/workorder/practice/*.wor", 0, NULL, &globbuf);

for (size_t i = 0; i < globbuf.gl_pathc; i++)
{
    char *filename = globbuf.gl_pathv[i];
    // Process filename...
}

globfree(&globbuf);
```

Comment: thank you.  It works now.  Do you by any chance know why my counter is not working? it still displays "total files scanned is 0."  Thanks!

Comment: @DaveWang: The statement `c = c++;` is *undefined behavior* because you're modifying `c` twice in one expression.  You want to write it either as just `c++;` or as `c = c + 1;`.